# How to update multiple dictionary key-value without using for loop

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a list of dictionaries with the same keys but different values.
Example:

```
[{ 'Price' : 100, 'Quantity' : 3 }, { 'Price' : 200, 'Quantity' : 5 }]
```

Is there a way to update the value of a particular key in all dictionaries in one go without using for loop?

That is, is there a way to make Quantity=0 for all dictionaries in the list in one go?

I am looking for performance since I have a huge list of dictionaries, and I'm under the assumption that there may be a faster way to do this than using a for loop. I have. gone through multiple questions on stack overflow but did not get any satisfactory response.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to have this as a list of dictionaries? Converting it to either a numpy array or a pandas dataframe would allow you to perform very fast vectorized operations very easily.

Comment: some times you have to use for even you are trying to high your program performance because there is no way to do that thing without using for , especially if the values are not the same. and also you can give us the purpose of using dictionaries to see how can we help you.

Comment: `without loops` is somethjng we try to do with numpy arrays - by using loops in compiled methods. That isn't an option when working with python lists and dicts,

Answer (score 2):

As proposed in comments, you can do something like this (I also recommend not to stay with your dictionaries):

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {"price": 10, "qty": 100}
d2 = {"price": 50, "qty": 110}

# create dataframe from dictionaries
df = pd.DataFrame([d1, d2])

# process all values in the column at once
df["qty"] = 0

print(df)

# if you really want your dictionaries back, you can do this
d1, d2 = df.to_dict("rows")
```

Comment: I wonder if pandas is actually doing the dict interfacing faster, or is it just hiding details.

Comment: It will need to do the same things, I dont think this per se will result in performance gains. However, the intermediary dataframe representation can help to perform many other tasks (that OP might need to perform) much faster. E.g. all sorts of conditional indexing. So this is a somewhat clean alternative, I guess?